# Duplex communication with net.tcp: How to get return value from CallbackContract

Tags: silverlight, wcf

```
//WCF Services Code:
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "Silverlight", CallbackContract = typeof(IStockServiceClient))]
    public interface IStockService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
        void Connect();
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IStockServiceClient
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        int SendUpdate(string value);
    }

    public class StockService : IStockService
    {
        private static IStockServiceClient client;
        public void Connect()
        {
            client = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IStockServiceClient>();
        }
        public static IStockServiceClient Client
        {
            get
            {
                return client;
            }
        }
    }

//Call Silverlight Code
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var result = DuplexStockService.Web.StockService.Client.
                SendUpdate("test");
    }


//silverlight code
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
            ServiceReference1.StockServiceClient client =
                new ServiceReference1.StockServiceClient();
            client.ConnectAsync();
            client.SendUpdateReceived += (senderSendUpdateReceived, eSendUpdateReceived) =>
                {
                    //return 1; //Doesn't work
                    //How to return a value back to WCF?
                };
   }
```

The callback method  int SendUpdate(string value) is supposed to return an int value,but how can the silverlight's SendUpdateReceived event handler return an int value back to its wcf callee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return any value if your operation contract is marked as `OneWay`. All one way operations must return `void` because the client never waits for their response - that's why they are called one way.

Comment: if I remove the OneWay attribute, what should I do next to get the return value?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not supported in Silverlight - the callbacks can only be one-way operations that do not return values. This is an additional restriction placed on duplex services by Silverlight - in non-Silverlight WCF, you can specify any return type that you desire.